# Android 2.2 app: No gps signal after 30 minutes. Works again after 30 minutes doing nothing

Tags: android, gps

I'm working on a HTC Legend and try to build my own gps logging app. Everything works as expected beside the fact, that I have a gap of 30 minutes in every track.

This gap where I do not get gps data is always around minutes 30 to 60 - so after 30 minutes of activity, I have no gps data for 30 minutes. And without doing anything (not even restarting the app), it starts collecting data again after this 30 minutes break.

Does anyone have an explanation for this? It's driving me crazy...

Forgot to mention that I collect data with the straight forward requestLocationUpdates stuff, but no issues here...

EDIT: Code sample as requested:

```
    private LocationListener ll = new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        }   

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }   
};
```

And here's the corresponding NMEA listener because I will handle raw GPS data:

```
GpsStatus.NmeaListener nl = new GpsStatus.NmeaListener() {

    @Override
    public void onNmeaReceived(long timestamp, String nmea) {
        /*
         * Use patcher and matcher to find a proper GPRMC sentence and remove symbols at the end like \n, # etc.
         */
        m = p.matcher(nmea);
        Log.d(LocationLoggerApp.TAG, "Time for a break...");
        //Notify activity that app is ready for upload
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("LOG", "Got valid GPRMC sentence");
        sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
};
```

And here we have the line from the onStart function where above stuff is "loaded":

```
/*
     * Request location updates as workaround because the function addNmeaListner DOES NOT enable GPS on the phone!
     */
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, interval*1000, 0, ll);
    lm.addNmeaListener(nl);
```

Regards,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

Any chance of some code samples? My first suggestion is to check you've set your minTime and minDistance parameters correctly.

```
public void requestLocationUpdates (long minTime, float minDistance, Criteria criteria, PendingIntent intent)
```

Comment: I've added the samples to my first post. But this is definitely not the issue because it works before and after the 30min break. If minTime and minDistance would be wrong, then I shouldn't get data at all. Or am I thinking wrong here?

Comment: I can't see anything obvious there that should cause 30 minutes on/30 minutes off location data. As you say this always happens I think you should conduct some tests. For starters I would try downloading GPS Test (free version) from the Android Market, and run it at the same time as your logger. See if when both are run for an hour the GPS fix is lost during the second half hour. If that's the case you know it's not your program that is at fault.